# How can I take DocEntry from UDO form of SAP B1 in SDK?

Tags: sapb1

How can I take DocEntry from UDO form of SAP B1 in SDK?

I tried to take UDF, it works fine

```
Dim oForm As SAPbouiCOM.Form = SBO_Application.Forms.Item(SBO_Application.Forms.ActiveForm.UDFFormUID)
Dim oDocEntry As SAPbouiCOM.EditText = CType(oForm.Items.Item("U_Member").Specific, SAPbouiCOM.EditText)
Dim SelectedValueID As String = Convert.ToString(oDocEntry.Value)
Dim ID As Integer = SelectedValueID
```

But if I replace U_Member with DocEntry like this

```
Dim oForm As SAPbouiCOM.Form = SBO_Application.Forms.Item(SBO_Application.Forms.ActiveForm.UDFFormUID)
Dim oDocEntry As SAPbouiCOM.EditText = CType(oForm.Items.Item("DocEntry").Specific, SAPbouiCOM.EditText)
Dim SelectedValueID As String = Convert.ToString(oDocEntry.Value)
Dim ID As Integer = SelectedValueID
```

I get error message Add-on 9000012 failed with exception; Event Type:1

How can I solve this issue?

Please anyone can help me

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to get the Item by the alias "DocEntry" - but there isn't an Item with that alias.

The UI elements don't generally use aliases which follow the database fields - they typically just numeric string identifiers e.g. `"8"` (which is the DocEntry EditText Item on Financial documents e.g. Orders, Invoices, etc).

If you want to check what the alias of the element is, turn on System Information (View => System Information, Ctrl+Shift+I) and mouse over the field. Look for the Item Alias in the bottom bar.

[image]